# Any solution found for word-wrap in VF PDF?

Tags: visualforce, pdf, css, line-break

Searched nearly one day but could'nt find the solution for this. There are lot of questions regarding word-wrap is not working on pdf but none of them have answers.

am just fetching the contacts email like below

```
<td>{!Contact.Email__c}</td>
```

**Problem** : Whenever the contact email is large/big one then it should break the line.

Used all those css properites like **word-wrap, overflow, break-word, white-space**.... but no use of these.

Somewhere I found that CSS3 properties are not supported by PDF generating engine.

Any solution for this?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I think its the email as a continuous string without spaces that will prevent you from wrapping, all of the css will be ignored because it doesn't know where to wrap. I think your only option is to clip the content to a max-width using  overflow: hidden;

Comment: Also, css3 won't work with VF PDF, it is only css2 compliant

Comment: No use of hidden property.  Also i dont want to clip.

Comment: If text is hidden then we can't see the text

Answer (score 2):

In case of plain text,you can  use \r\n.You can try using a VisualForce component

Component(Develop->Visualforce components):Add the following

```
 <apex:component controller="break" access="global" >

<apex:outputText value="{!break}" />
```

Controller:In classes

```
public class break {

public String break {

    get { return '\r\n'; }

    set;

}
```

And use the component's id in visualforce page:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!Contact.Email__c}" var="c">

    <apex:outputText value="{!c.ID}" />

    <c:break />
```

Comment: tried, not working @Pri

Comment: Try the above method.

Comment: i don't know how to use apex:component. Could you show me the vf page with all the components(apex:component and apex:repeat) inside apex:page

Comment: I have modified the above answer for your understanding.Check whether you can get anything from it.

Comment: Unknown constructor 'break.break(ApexPages.StandardController controller)'